# how to get Apple "command button" key code programmatically?

Tags: macos, shortcut, keycode

i need to know what key code of Command button in mac keyboard, do somebody know how to get it programmatically?

can i get the key code if user tap button Command + X (cut shortcut)? thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that you're dealing with NSEvents generated by the AppKit framework.

In NSEvent's documentation, take a look at the [`modifierFlags`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/modifierFlags) method.

And the flag you're lookng for is specifically the [`NSCommandKeyMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCommandKeyMask).

Now, to get it, if you have a NSView view in focus... it inherits from NSResponder.  One of the methods in NSResponder is [`keyDown`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/keyDown%3a).  So add a `keyDown` method to your subclassed view and the parameter it takes is a `NSEvent`.  And that is how you would get your command button key.

***BTW & FYI***, if you just want to get the command key by itself (which is what I suspect), that's a bigger trick and I'm not sure if it's possible with AppKit.  Because the command key, like the control and shift keys, are *modifier* keys and that means when events get generated, NSEvent is expecting two keys to be pressed at the same time (e.g. Command + Q for Quit, Control + C for interrupt, Shift + A for capital A).

Comment: thank you for the answer @Michael, can you tell me how to get it code? can you give me an example?

Comment: I added some more detail to my answer (you can catch a NSEvent happening by subclassing your view and implementing your own `keyDown` method).  I hope this helps you out.