# How to disable cmd+q on mac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm creating a time tracker application for mac. I used the following code to run the application on full screen mode and it works perfectly.

```
[[self.window contentView] enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:nil]
```

but still the application can be closed with cmd+q. Is there any way that i can prevent from closing the application?

Comment: I'd advise *against* doing this, this is bad user experience, though I am certain it's possible as there is a game I play which annoys me by disabling it!

Comment: I am agree with @JamesWebster, however here's a quick search result for you, it may help you to get in logic. [Source1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648957/how-to-get-apple-command-button-key-code-programmatically) [Source2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155015/handle-cmd-q-in-cocoa-application-and-menu-item-quit-application-programmatic) Also [**Apple's Doc - Handling key events**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html)

Comment: Its requirement so i have to implement it and thanks for the quick reply @JamesWebster

Comment: i already viewed those posts but i couldn't figure it out since i am new to Objective-c but thanks for the quick reply. i will go through them again @Hemang

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the main xib file you have the main menu.

Under the first menu item (the name of the app), you have the quit option.

Simply removing that menu item solve your problem.

If you prefer, you can only remove the shortcut.

[image: Menu item quit]

Comment: Is it possible to disable the command + Q option using java? @usain

Comment: Holy Jobs! That's a pretty undocumented way to remove the `CMD + Q` capability...